# Find previous and next images in div with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to find the next and previous image starting from the img with the 'active' class within a div. The problem is, the search for the previous and next image always return a length of 0, so nothing happens.

```
<style>
.container #left img{
display:hidden;
}

.container #left img.active{
display:block;
}
</style>

<div class="container">

<div id="left">

<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="2.jpg" />
<img src="3.jpg" />
<img src="4.jpg" />
<img src="5.jpg" />

</div>

</div>

<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>

<script>
$('.container #left img:first-child').addClass('active');

    $(document).off('click', '.arrow-left').on('click', '.arrow-left', function() {
        var prev = $('.container #left img.active').closest('div').prev().find('img');
        if (prev.length == 0) {
            prev = $('.container #left img:last');
        }
        $('.container #left img').removeClass('active');
        prev.addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: unrelated but aren't all of the .container calls redundant if you have an id on a div that should be unique so can't you address everything just by #left

Comment: Just use `$('.container #left img.active').prev('img')` should work. See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLoq4L3b/). And as @johnny5 says, its not necessary to use `.container #left`, as `#left` should be unique.

Comment: Yes, the .container calls are redundant within the script. I'll clean up unnecessary code later.  fuyushimoya solved the question " $('.container #left img.active').prev('img')  " does indeed work.

Comment: Patriotec you should upvote @fuyushimoya since he answer your question correctly

Comment: I upvoted fuyushimoya's comment long ago. If he would post the answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As what I commented, you can use [.next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to find the immediately following/preceding sibling. And as `id` should be unique, the class `.container` is not necessary here.

So you can rewrite the selector to :

```
$('#left img.active').prev('img')
```

To select the previous image.

And you can re-use the logic of left and right by using `.is('arrow-left')` to decide whether the user clicked left or right.

```js
$('.container #left img:first-child').addClass('active');

$(document).off('click', '.arrow-left, .arrow-right').on('click', '.arrow-left, .arrow-right', function() {
  var next;
  var circler;
  if ($(this).is('.arrow-left')) {
    next = 'prev';
    circler = ':last';
  } else {     // or if there would be more arrows, use : else if ($(this).is('.arrow-right'))
    next = 'next';
    circler = ':first';
  }
  
  // Use bracket notation to dynamically decide which function to call.
  var nextTarget = $('#left img.active')[next]('img');
  if (nextTarget.length == 0) {
    nextTarget = $('#left img' + circler);
  }
  $('#left img').removeClass('active');
  nextTarget.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#left img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#left img.active {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.arrow-left, .arrow-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<div id="left">
  <img src="1.jpg" />
  <img src="2.jpg" />
  <img src="3.jpg" />
  <img src="4.jpg" />
  <img src="5.jpg" />
</div>

</div>

<div class="arrow-left">Left</div>
<div class="arrow-right">Right</div>
```